# Hosts file - Many entries

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file

I noticed *Spybot - Search & Destroy* adds almost 15k entries on the hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) if you decide to immunize. Does this decrease the computer performance, **significantly** (let's say seconds), in any way (boot, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the system, I stopped using it because it slowed my Internet browsing performance,  it has no effect on boot time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: As tagged, Windows.

Comment: I've voted you up, but I must point out that the hosts file, when loaded into memory, consumes very few resources. Internet Explorer freaks out with a big file for some reason, but (in my experience with no empirical evidence) Windows manages fine with this size, and other browsers are fine too.

Comment: Like I said it depends on the system, I had one PC that it caused browsing to become very slow, removed spybot hosts file and it returned to normal speeds. Just my experience with it. Thanks for the vote Randolph.